# Do the "catchable" types of fish vary by time of day?

Tags: happy-street

Once you have obtained the [Fisherman Cabin](http://happystreet.wikia.com/wiki/Fisherman_Cabin), fish begin to appear in the river for you to catch.  You get to catch 3 fish, and then the season is over for 3 hours (where you can't catch fish and you have to wait).  The fish you catch seem to be somewhat random, but I've noticed that I tend to catch fish which look like an [anglerfish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anglerfish) only when it is night.  Is it just luck, or do some fish only appear at certain times of day?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Happy Street wikia](http://happystreet.wikia.com/wiki/Crafting_Supplies_&_Items#Trout), the "Anglerfish" which produce the Pearl of Light item only appear at night.  Its not clearif the trout, carp, and salmon only appear during the day, but that has been my experience.

Answer (score 0):

Well the pearl of light, can only be found at "night" in the game, but the others are found during the day the one I seem to not of found is the salmon. I guess the salmon is more rare?